# Calculation - numpy python bug 

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, bug-tracking

I am using NumPy to do some calculation on finding the Y intercept, through an Aperture between a big box and a small box. I have over 100.000 particles in the big box, and around 1000 in the small one. And it's taking a lot of time to do so. All the self.YD, self.XD are very large arrays that i'm multiplying.

PS: The ind are indexes of the values that need to be multiplied. I had a nonzero condition before that line in my code.

Any ideas how I would do this calculation in a simpler way?

```
YD_zero = self.oldYD[ind] - ((self.oldYD[ind]-self.YD[ind]) * self.oldXD[ind])/(self.oldXD[ind]-self.XD[ind])
```

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

Would using multiply, divide, subtract and all that stuff of Numpy. make it faster?
Or if maybe if i split the calculation. for example.

to do this first:

```
    YD_zero = self.oldYD[ind] - ((self.oldYD[ind]-self.YD[ind])*self.oldXD[ind])
```

and then the next line would be:

```
    YD_zero /= (self.oldXD[ind]-self.XD[ind])
```

Any suggestions?!

**UPDATE 2**

I have been trying to figure this out, in a while now, but not much progress. My concern is that the denominator :

```
    self.oldXL[ind]-self.XL[ind] == 0
```

and I am getting some weird results.

The other thing is the nonzero function. I have been testing it for a while now. Could anybody tell me that it is almost the same as find in Matlab

Comment: Is the loss of precision significant if you try trim the sets of points?

Comment: I need to have really accurate data.

Comment: By simpler, do you mean in fewer cpu cycles?

Comment: I have this inside a while loop, and do it at least 16000 times in one run. So, whatever would make this calculation faster.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps I have got the wrong end of the stick but in Numpy you can perform vectorised calculations. Remove the enclosing `while` loop and just run this ...

`YD_zero = self.oldYD - ((self.oldYD - self.YD) * self.oldXD) / (self.oldXD - self.XD)`

It should be much faster.

**Update:** Iterative root finding using the Newton-Raphson method ...

```
unconverged_mask = np.abs(f(y_vals)) > CONVERGENCE_VALUE:
while np.any(unconverged_mask):
    y_vals[unconverged_mask] = y_vals[unconverged_mask] - f(y_vals[unconverged_mask]) / f_prime(y_vals[unconverged_mask])
    unconverged_mask = np.abs(f(y_vals)) > CONVERGENCE_VALUE:
```

This code is only illustrative but it shows how you can apply an iterative process using vectorised code to any function `f` which you can find the derivative of `f_prime`. The `unconverged_mask` means that the results of the current iteration will only be applied to those values that have not yet converged.

*Note that in this case there is no need to iterate, Newton-Raphson will give you the correct answer in the first iteration since we are dealing with straight lines. What you have is an exact solution.*

**Second update**

Ok, so you aren't using Newton-Raphson. To calculate `YD_zero` (the y intercept) in one go, you can use,

`YD_zero = YD + (XD - X0) * dYdX`

where `dYdX` is the gradient, which seems to be, in your case,

`dYdX = (YD - oldYD) / (XD - oldXD)`

I am assuming `XD` and `YD` are the current x,y values of the particle, `oldXD` and `oldYD` are the previous x,y values of the particle and `X0` is the x value of the aperture.

Still not entirely clear why you have to iterate over all the particles, Numpy can do the calculation for all particles at once.

Comment: If you vectorize it, it also allows for the ability to later move to the GPU if you really need the speed.

Comment: I did vectorize it, but I have plenty of other things in the loop. I think this is taking longer than everything else. Because I've ran it without this, and it was a lot more faster.

Comment: I believe the loop is not on the index, but rather for the iterative Newton algorithm.

Comment: Ah right, so you are using the Newton-Raphson method to find zeros in a function? If so, the updated code may be of help.

Comment: Also be aware that since we are dealing with straight lines, there is no need to apply the Newton-Raphson equation more than once, it will be correct on the first iteration.

Comment: The particles in my boxes can travel through the boxes and hit the walls, I have to perform other tests. I can't use the Newton-Raphson method because the lines may change variation and not go through the aperture all the time.

Answer (score 2):

Since all the computations are done element-wise, it should be easy to re-write the expression in [`Cython`](http://cython.org/). This will avoid all those very large temporary array that get created when you do `oldYD-YD` and such.

Another possibility is [`numexpr`](http://code.google.com/p/numexpr/).

Comment: How would I multiply two arrays with Numexpr or Cython?! And would you rather suggest Cython or Numexpr?

Comment: @theSun: What is it specifically about multiplication that's causing confusion? As to `Cython` vs `numexpr`, the latter should be easier to get right. However, I personally have only used the former so there could be subtleties around `numexpr` that I am not aware of.

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely go for `numexpr`. I'm not sure `numexpr` can handle indices, but I bet that the following (or something similar) would work:

```
import numexpr as ne

yold = self.oldYD[ind]
y = self.YD[ind]
xold = self.oldXD[ind]
x = self.XD[ind]
YD_zero = ne.evaluate("yold - ((yold - y) * xold)/(xold - x)")
```